# Tag Email Sends

Tags: marketing-cloud, tracking-extract

We want to analyse email sends from marketing cloud within our data warehouse, and to run an effective analysis, we plan to tag all email sends (manual/Journeys/Automation email sends) with proper tags.

Is there any option to do global tagging for email sends? We already thought about campaigns, but as we only can assign only one campaign per send, it doesn't really meet our requirement.

Comment: What do you want to tag? Links in emails or the content assets?

Comment: @StephandePaly the actual email sends.

Answer (score 1):

There may be better ways to do this, but the approach I've previously taken is adding a "Tag" column to my sendable DEs with a default value, and additionally a "Tag" column as my SendLog, which will capture the value as emails are sent.

Comment: I was thinking along a similar line, only not through a column in the send data extension but by using ampscript variables, which can also be pushed into the data extension. That should allow a pretty flexible solution